# Is there a difference between the three dependency injection syntaxes in Blazor (.net 7)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, blazor

As far as I can tell, all three of these patterns work to inject a DI service in a Blazor (.net 7/C#/Razor) project:

1. `@inject NavigationManager NavManager` in the Razor component
2. `[Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }` in the class definiton
3. The typical DI pattern:

```cs
   private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;
   public Index2Model(IMyDependency myDependency)
   {
       _myDependency = myDependency;            
   }
```

As far as I can tell, they all work.

Is there any difference in their implementation? Is it safe to use any or all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) and 2) are called Property Injection, 3) is Constructor Injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional Information to Dimitris's answer.

Yes there is a difference between 1/2 and 3.  A component's injection process (handled by the Renderer process) is run after the Ctor.  You can't use any DI services in the Ctor.

The difference between 1 and 2 is nullability.

1. With `@inject`, the Razor compiler disables nullable checking for the property.
2. With `[Inject]`, you need to handle it manually.  The normal way to do this is to set `default!` as the default value.  It will never be null once you get to `SetParametersAsync` and the normal lifecycle methods as the runtime will throw an exception during the injection process if it can't find the service.

```cs
[Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; } = default!;
```

Answer (score 5):

Only difference is that the first two syntaxes you mentioned should be used in Razor components while the third syntax should be used in all other cases.

`@inject NavigationManager NavManager` syntax is used to inject services in Razor components using mark-up.

`[Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }` is used to inject services in Razor components using C# code. (Inside `@code { ... }` section or inside the partial class in code-behind approach).

You can use both approaches in the same component.

```
@inject IToDoApi ToDoApi
@inject ISomeServiceType AnotherService

@code
{
  [Inject]
  private IYetAnotherServiceType PropertyInjectedDependency { get; set; }
}
```

The constructor syntax is used to inject a service to another service.

```cs
public class NewsletterService : INewsletterService
{
  private readonly IEmailService EmailService;

  public NewsletterService(IEmailService emailService)
  {
    EmailService = emailService;
  }
}
```

[Request a service in a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#request-a-service-in-a-component)

Code snippets were from: [Injecting dependencies into Blazor components](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/injecting-dependencies-into-blazor-components/#Injecting-dependencies)

Comment: These were both good answers, but I found Mr. C's to be a bit more helpful in my case. Thank you as well!