# Constructor injection possible in Blazor Wasm code-behind .razor.cs file?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I understand that in Blazor components with code-behind files, we inject depedencies as properties:

```
public partial class MyComponent : IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    ILogger<MyComponent> Logger { get; set;}

    [Inject]
    NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to inject through regular constructor injection? And if not why is this?

```
public MyComponent(ILogger<MyComponent> logger, NavigationManager navigationManager)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _navigationManager = navigationManager;
}
```

I'm just curious as property-injection is a different way of working, for instance I'm expecting to refer to my dependencies through the e.g. `_navigationManager` syntax, but if they're properties then it should be `NavigationManager`?

I know I'm splitting hairs, but consistency can be a time saver.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18088
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75014794/is-there-a-difference-between-the-three-dependency-injection-syntaxes-in-blazor

Comment: While this question is similar to the once referred to, the answers provided don't directly answer the question here.  I would provide an answer but the bot has closed the question.

Comment: Inject in components is a little different to resolving dependancies in the service container.  The RenderTree uses the `Inject` attribute to find properties that need to be injected. It uses `IServiceProvider` and reflection to actually assign values to the properties.  Only properties, not global variables can have attributes.  You can inject `IServiceProvider` into the component and then use it to directly assign DI objects to globsl variables in `OnInitialized`.  I would show you some code, but alas question closed....

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis When you see that "Community [Bot]" has close a question as a duplicate, it means that the OP answered "yes" to the "Does this answer your question?" question, instigated by the first close vote. And there's nothing stopping you from posting another answer to the linked duplicate, if you feel that would be useful.

Comment: [Polite]  @AdrianMole - np, thanks for the clarification.